# Google Cloud SDK installation fails on Windows 10

Tags: google-cloud-platform, sdk, windows-10, cloud

When I tried to install Google Cloud SDK, it fails:

> Welcome to the Google Cloud SDK!
>   To use the Google Cloud SDK, you must have Python installed and on your PATH.
>   As an alternative, you may also set the CLOUDSDK_PYTHON environment variable
>   to the location of your Python executable.
>   Google Cloud SDK installer will now exit.
>   Press any key to continue . . .

I installed Python and copied `system32` path in system variable and environment variable even, but still fails. What's going wrong?

Comment: Double check that you have Python 2.7 installed and set up in your path. Reboot your system and open a command prompt and type `python -V`. Python 3 is supported by the latest version released this week but I would stick with Python 2.7 for installing the CLI. You can use Python 3 after the CLI is set up.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem some time ago, this is how I solved it:

1. uninstall cloud sdk (delete also the folder), uninstall python
2. reboot you system
3. launch the installer and select "install bundled python"
4. when the installer asks for an installation path, point to "C:\Users\YOUR_USER\AppData\Roaming\gcloud"

I had a problem with my windows installation since I had different permissions set on the default path suggested which was "Program Files (x86)". 
Starting fresh + changing path fixed the issue for me :)

also review [this page](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/downloads-interactive), to see if everything is in check for you